# Angular *ngIf Property ngIf is not provided by any applicable directive on an embedded template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular16

I try to use ngIf but I have an error, *ngIf has red underline. that error is : " Property ngIf is not provided by any applicable directive on an embedded template  "

I tried to import commonModel then I get this error : " src/app/view/Home/home.component.ts:12:11 - error NG2010: 'imports' is only valid on a component that is standalone.

12   imports:[
~
13     CommonModule

````
14   ]
~~~ "

Note: Version = angular16

component.ts : 


```
import {CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: './home.component.html',
providers: [CommonModule],
imports:[
 CommonModule
]
})
```


```
<div *ngIf="index.rate>0; else down" class="col-6">
               <p class="text-green-500 pi pi-arrow-up" >{{index.rate}}</p>
             </div>
             <ng-template #down>
             <div class="col-6">
               <p class="text-red-500 pi pi-arrow-up" >{{index.rate}}</p>
             </div>
             </ng-template>
```


I tried import common model but it didnt work I get new error
````

Comment: I did it but didn't work. Still *ngIf has red underline.

Comment: Yes I get : " Property ngIf is not provided by any applicable directive on an embedded template  " on command line

Comment: pls share your module's code

Comment: and try removing import and providers array from your component. make sure you have CommonModule in your feature module's imports array

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering is related to the usage of `*ngIf` and the import of `CommonModule`. In Angular, you typically don't need to import `CommonModule` in your component file because it is automatically imported in the `AppModule` when you create a new Angular application.

Here's how to resolve the issue:

1. Remove the `import { CommonModule }` line from your component file (component.ts). It's not needed there.
2. Make sure you have the `CommonModule` imported in your `AppModule`. This is where you need to import it to use directives like `*ngIf`:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; // Import CommonModule here

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule, // Add CommonModule to your imports here
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3. Once you've removed the import of `CommonModule` from your component file and added it to your `AppModule`, your `*ngIf` directive should work without any issues in your component's template:

```html
<div *ngIf="index.rate > 0; else down" class="col-6">
  <p class="text-green-500 pi pi-arrow-up">{{ index.rate }}</p>
</div>
<ng-template #down>
  <div class="col-6">
    <p class="text-red-500 pi pi-arrow-up">{{ index.rate }}</p>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

By following these steps, you should be able to use `*ngIf` without any problems in your Angular component.

Comment: I add my app.module can you check it

Answer (score 0):

I feel you has a little confusion between Modules, Components and standalone Components.

Take a look the [Introduction to Angular concepts](https://angular.io/guide/architecture)

In brief:

1. One Component (not standalone) are declared in a Module
2. One Module can imports anothers modules
3. A service can be "provided" to all the application or for a Module
4. One component only can use others components or directives
   that are declared in the same module it is (or in a module imported
   in the module)
5. The standalone components not need be declared in any Module, but we need import the modules we need

So, not "I tried to import commonModel". It's not add code in anywhere just by chance